# Default null anchor in yaml

Tags: javascript, yaml

I want to define in the default as null in Swagger.yaml :

```
MYKey: &CONST_MY_KEY null
```

But this does not work. However, an empty string fine as shown below :

```
MYKey: &CONST_MY_KEY ""
```

Comment: An empty string is not a null, keep in mind that `""` still has a `\0` bytecode